# Reading Greek Characters form a file on c++

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw-w64

Hi I am new on C++ but I have experience on other languages
I have the following code:

```
enter code here
    streampos begin,end;        
    char delimeter[3] = {',', '\n', '\0'};
    int numChars = 0;
    int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, startIndex = 0, studentIndex = 0;
    ifstream file1("Students1.csv", ios::in);
    if (!file1) throw MyExceptions();
    begin = file1.tellg();
    file1.seekg (0, ios::end);
    end = file1.tellg();
    int size =  end - begin;
    file1.seekg(0, ios::beg);      
    char charField[size];         
    while(file1.getline(charField, size, '\n'))
    { 
        char *tmpCharField1 = charField;                        
        numChars = file1.gcount();
        CustomString tmpStudent(tmpCharField1, numChars);
        pos1 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[0], startIndex);
        CustomString tmpStudentCode = tmpStudent.subString(startIndex, pos1);
        pos2 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[0], (pos1 + 1));
        CustomString tmpFirstName = tmpStudent.subString((pos1 + 1), pos2);
        pos3 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[2], (pos2 + 1));
        CustomString tmpSecondName = tmpStudent.subString((pos2 + 1), pos3);
        Student *student1 = new Student(tmpStudentCode, tmpFirstName, tmpSecondName);
        this->StudentVector.push_back(student1);
        studentIndex++; 
    }        
    file1.close();
```

I am trying to read a file with Greek letters where the file is as this:

```
 SR000001,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0001,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0001
 SR000002,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0002,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0002
 SR000003,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0003,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0003
 SR000004,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0004,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0004
 SR000005,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0005,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0005
 SR000006,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0006,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0006
 SR000007,ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ 0007,ΟΝΟΜΑ 0007`
```

The format is on UTF8, I use NetBeans 8.1 on Windows 10 64 bit machine with MINGW-64. How can I read the Greek letters as 1 byte data? Please do not say me that the reading is not ok, I have to do an assignment without using string or string methods…

Comment: If it's UTF-8 then those are multibyte characters. You can't read them as 1 byte. In UTF-8 Ω should be the byte sequence E2 84 A6.

Comment: There are tricks with some editors where you can make the them one byte

Comment: Those "tricks" are called changing the encoding from UTF-8. It is absolutely, categorically impossible to represent "Ω" in UTF-8 in one byte. There is [Code Page 737](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_737) which is an 8-bit representation of Greek, but it's not the only one. It is notably not UTF-8 and requires conversion from multi-byte UTF-8 to 8-bit CP737.